# Is there a method to disable onsend web add-in quickly for all users in the tenant?

Tags: outlook-web-addins

My client complains that disabling a custom onsend web add-in for Outlook takes about 2 hours.
How they can do that more quick?

Comment: What do you mean by "disabling" is this uninstalling via centralized deployment? or what specifically?

Comment: Hi Juan. In fact I mean how to prevent the add-in to delay messages. Let's suppose the add-in is hosted somewhere and the hoster's site is down. It means all users who run the add-in can't send at all. How to allow them to send as soon as possible?

Comment: To prevent the add-in from running, the add-in needs to removed or turned off. How is the add-in deployed? Add-ins can be turned off from Manage Add-ins: https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/turn-an-add-in-off-for-outlook-for-windows-96737da4-ab7c-464e-9d2a-cf15db47c4cf

Comment: The problem is that removing takes quite long time.

Comment: Currently, uninstalling or turning off the add-in is the only way to stop an onSend add-in from running. We track Outlook add-in feature requests on our user-voice page. Please add your request there. Feature requests on user-voice are considered, when we go through our planning process. https://officespdev.uservoice.com/forums/224641-general/category/131778-outlook-add-ins